# What is the right way to expand these bash strings to the right Git commands?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-expansion

I am having a go at writing some basic bash scripts and the expansion of these strings into `Git` commands is proving problematic.

The idea is pass the script a top level directory whose sub-directories contain Git repositories and run the same command on the sub directories with the option of `tee`ing the output to a file.

The problem is that the git commands which have extra options don't work correctly. So the `diff` and `status` commands work. `remote` works, but `remote show origin` doesn't work. For instance the `r` and `e` options don't work.

```
processing /home/vfclists/project1/
git: 'remote -v' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

processing /home/vfclists/project1/
git: 'remote show origin' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Does the problem come from the `bash` expansion or from `Git` itself, or both?

```
#!/bin/bash

usage()
{
cat << EOF
checkrepos command output file

usage: $0 options

OPTIONS:

  commands 
    r remote show origin
    d diff
    s status
    e remote
  other options
   -d    directory
   -t    filename for tee
EOF
}

WD=$(pwd)
echo "working directory $WD"

while getopts "c:t:v:h:" OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
         c)
         case $OPTARG in
           r)
             COMMAND="remote show origin"
             ;;
           d)
             COMMAND="diff"
             ;;
           s)
             COMMAND="status"
             ;;
           e)
             COMMAND="remote -v"
             ;;
         esac
         ;;
         t)
             OUTPUTFILE=$OPTARG
             ;;
         v)
             VERBOSE=1
             ;;
         h)
             usage
             exit 1
             ;;
         ?)
             usage
             exit
             ;;
     esac
done

if  [[ -z $COMMAND ]]
then
    echo 'command is required'
    usage
    exit 1
fi



for d in $WD/* ; do
  echo ""
  echo "===================="
  echo ""
  echo "processing $d"

  git -C "$d"  "$COMMAND"
  echo ""
  echo "===================="
  echo ""
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the `r` case as an example, with

```
COMMAND="remote show origin"
```

followed by

```
git -C "$d" "$COMMAND"
```

`git` sees three arguments, `-C`, the value of `d`, and `remote show origin`, instead of the five it expects (`remote`, `show` and `origin` separately instead of `remote show origin`).

With `bash`, simply removing the quotes will fix this:

```
git -C "$d" $COMMAND
```

With Zsh, you need to split the string using

```
git -C "$d" $=COMMAND
```

(thanks [ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu) and [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles)!).

Comment: just `git -C "$d" $COMMAND` will do (as long as the variable doesn't contain anything that looks like a glob)

Comment: Does having $COMMAND  quoted mean that `Git` receives the commands with the quotes around them eg `git -C dir "remote -v"` or `git -C dir "remote show origin"`?

Comment: @vfclists No. With the quotes, git receives e.g. `remove -v` as a single argument. The quotes are part of the shell syntax, they aren't part of the argument.

Comment: That's a silly way to split in zsh. The non-silly way is `$=COMMAND`. But splitting a string is itself silly in both bash and zsh. `COMMAND` is a list of strings, so make it an array.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the variable `COMMAND` to store a list of strings, but it's a string variable, not a list variable. The instruction `git -C "$d"  "$COMMAND"` expands to four words: `git`, `-C`, the value of the variable `d` and the value of the variable `COMMAND`. If the value of `COMMAND` is e.g. `remote -v` then the third argument on the command line of `git` is `remote -v`, which git doesn't understand.

To pass separate arguments, store them in a list of strings, i.e. an [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays). “Array” in shell programming means a list of strings.

```
COMMAND=()
…
  e) COMMAND=(remote -v);;
…
if ((${#COMMAND[@]} == 0)); then
  echo >&2 "Missing command"
  usage >&2
  exit 2
fi
…
git -d "$d" "${COMMAND[@]}"
```